Trying to use ETEKJOY ACR122U to add NFC to non-NFC Android phones. How's about app: MTools - Mifare ACR122 PN532?
The Motorola MOTO G PLAY is one of the very last Android phones that gets delivered (by XFinity Mobile) with no NFC capability. And yes, of course, I've got one. After numerous updates it runs Android 13. So along comes Ticketmaster with an ALL-NFC TICKET system. Tickets get stored in GOOGLE-WALLET. Frankly I'd rather spend $35 for a USB connected ACR122U run through an app than drop $150 to upgrade the phone. And when I do swap out the phone, move the ACR122U and download its app. Minimize security and data vulnerabilities. But is the MTools - Mifare ACR122 PN532 app up to it ?

That hardware was never intended for phones and it isn't officially supported in Android or (desktop) Linux although for the latter community drivers do exist. The chipset manufacturer supports Windows only. Also this is a reader, it isn't suitable for the purpose you intend.

Thank you. I do see it writing to the "poker chip" security tokens. And the Mifare app says it operates with Android -- that's writing IDs to the chips. My questions are whether it can present ticket data to a NFC reader ??? And access that ticket from Google Wallet ? I NEED TO ASK MTOOLS DIRECTLY.........
